# Does Genn Greymane's Cost Reduction Apply To Different Hero Powers?

Tags: hearthstone

Witchwood's release today will introduce a new card, Genn Greymane. This card reduces the cost of your hero power to 1 for the entire game. If your hero power is upgraded or changes, say with a Justicar Trueheart or through a Death Night, will this new hero power still cost 1 mana, or go back to 2? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hero power will return to costing (2) mana.  This is evident from the text reading

> your **starting** Hero Power costs (1).

(emphasis mine).  This is consistent with the effect of [Justicar Trueheart](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Justicar_Trueheart) which only upgrades the basic hero power you have at the beginning of the game*.  If you play her after you become Jaraxxus [she has no effect](https://twitter.com/CM_Whirthun/status/624271196440391681).

*If you change your baisc hero power with [Sir Finley Mrrgglton](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Sir_Finley_Mrrgglton), the new one you choose will be able to be upgraded by Justicar.  I don't believe this special case will carry over to Genn Graymane as the cost will likely reset as soon as your hero power changes.